# Change typeface on the fly spannable editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannable, android-typeface

I have a button:

```
if (id == R.id.italic) {
}
```

Inside that button I have a spannable:

```
int startSelection = noteContent.getSelectionStart()
int endSelection = noteContent.getSelectionEnd();
Spannable spannable = noteContent.getText();
```

When the user clicks the **italic button I want it to make the selected text in the spannable italic**. When the user **clicks the button on the same spannable text I want to make the selected text normal.**

What **if statement** will grab the typeface of the **spannable** so that it can italic or un italic.

Another way of putting it is the italic feature google implemented on there google drive for android. I want to do that.

Example two:

```
 If (spannable.getTypeface.equals(TypeFace.ITALIC) {


 } else {

 }
```

Of course the if statement code above isnt real but thats what im trying to find out

Thanks

Comment: what doesn't work in `Spannable#setSpan` and/or `Spannable#removeSpan` ?

Comment: nothing is wrong with those I want to get the typefaces of a spannabe

Comment: @Jordan check my updated answer i added i way so u can check if the typeface is bold or italic

Answer (score 0):

using this class you can set custom font or any fonts you want using spannable

```
public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

private final Typeface newType;

public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
    super(family);
    newType = type;
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
}

@Override
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
}

private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
    int oldStyle;
    Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
    if (old == null) {
        oldStyle = 0;
    } else {
        oldStyle = old.getStyle();
    }

    int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
    if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    }

    if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
        paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
    }

    paint.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

}

you can use it like this

```
  Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(Text.getText().toString());
            int index = public_desc.getText().toString().indexOf("any string you want");   

            wordtoSpan.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", Any type Face), index, text.getText().tostring().lenght, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            text.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

EDIT to turn this into if statement you can create a boolean for checked status be default it is false and when you click on the button then invert the value of that boolean and then if checked equal true set the spannable else set another font spannable

or you can use this to get if the typeface is with bold style or italic 
with this

```
    typefaceB.isBold() && typefaceA.isItalic()



     If (spannable.getTypeface.isItalic()) {


 } else {

 }
```

Comment: how can i turn this into an if statement so if i was to click the same text again it would go back to normal @Tony

Comment: This bolds all the text in the editText not just the spannable, am I doing something wrong? @Tony

Comment: so you want to bold a part of the text ?in spannable you can set the start and end index by this you can define the area which will be bolded

Comment: ok, check update Can I make An if statement like that that actually works @Tony you said something about boolean can yo please type an extample

Comment: is typeface A the boolean in this. (Example Boolean typefaceA) @Tony

Comment: i'm giving you an example on how to check the style of the typeface

Comment: in spannable.getTypeface getTypeface is red as if it does not exsist @Tony

Comment: Is there anyway to get the Typeface for a spannable not the whole editText how did google do it in google drive @Tony